# Synchronized charts - setExtremes works only on last chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to set min, max on chart1(yAxis) by clicking setExtremes button, But it works only on chart3(yAxis).

```
const A = {   
    setYaxis: 0,
    titleText: 'chartOne'
};
const B = {
    setYaxis: 1,
    titleText: 'chartTwo'
};
const C = { 
    setYaxis: 2,
    titleText: 'chartThree'
};
```

I set both titleText and setYaxis on yAxis.

titleText works, but setYaxis does not work.

```
yAxis :[{
       title: {
                 text: item.titleText
              },
       yAxis: item.setYaxis
}],
```

Trying to set for chart1, but this sets for chart3

```
 $('#minmax').click(function(){
          console.log("minmax")            
          chart1.yAxis[0].setExtremes(8, 10); 
   });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkfren2L/21/

I face the same issue for plotlines as well.  Now they appear only on last chart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because after the loop the `chart1` variable refers to the last created chart. You can store charts in an array. Moreover, to make all y-extremes synchronized, you need to call the `syncExtremes` function on `setExtremes` event from `yAxis`.

```
yAxis: [{
  ...,
  events: {
    setExtremes: syncExtremes
  }
}]
```

If it comes to the plot-lines, they are hidden because of the following setting:

```
xAxis: {
  visible: i === items.length - 1,
  ...
}
```

You should hide only xAxis labels:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: i === items.length - 1,
    format: '{value} time'
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9xLwa87q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis